# Video card overheating during installation of OS

Tags: drivers, installation, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have an ATI Radeon HD 5770 (made by Sapphire).  I'm currently trying to install Windows, however, my video card is overheating during installation and turning itself off.

I just switched mobos, but it happened on the previous one as well. (the old mobo had onboard video, though) Once windows is installed and the ATI drivers are installed the card stops overheating.

Any ideas on either how to fix the card or get it to work long enough to install windows? As of right now I get ~10 minutes, which is about 20% through expanding files.

Comment: Does the new mobo have any onboard video?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: after installing the drivers, the card underclocks unless you need it to perform... which is why it doesn't overheat after the drivers are installed.  The card shouldn't overheat in any case, which means you should probably be replacing the card instead of looking for a workaround.  But, if you just need it to work for installing Windows... increase your cooling.  Point a fan into the case with the side off... clean the fan and heatsink on the card, etc.

Comment: @BonGart The card performs fine under stress after the drivers are installed, though.

Comment: that's very odd... since the card doesn't perform fine under *actual* stress... at least the stress you describe.

Comment: @BonGart I don't understand why the card would be put under stress when messing with the BIOS or installing windows. I was able to install windows by swapping out cards until after windows was installed, played a game and the card performed fine.

Comment: I get it that you don't understand why it should be put under stress.  That doesn't change the fact that it currently *IS* being put under stress.  What you don't get, is that until the card is in an environment with it's hardware drivers active, it is at 100%.  Once the drivers have been loaded, it clocks down to 50% or less.  When you play a game, the card is not at 100% constantly.  But you just don't see, that if the card fails before the drivers have been loaded... that means the card is bad.